# How to bind mouse-over in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to bind an element so that when ever a mouse hovers over it, it will do something. What  modifier allows such bind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events. For example:

```
place [frame .f -width 100 -height 100 -bg red] -x 10 -y 10
bind .f <Enter> {%W configure -bg blue}
bind .f <Leave> {%W configure -bg red}
```